# Wpf RichTextBox - Getting text properties at Caret

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

When a user clicks say inside a word in a RichTextBox (Wpf) I need to get the text properties from the word or character preceding the Caret. Now they all work giving me the values i.e. FontFamily, FontSize & Foreground colour but I can't seem to get the Background colour.  Seems the property for Background returns a Brush value for use in setting the property later, I get a null here in this instance !  I have tried many ways of getting it but all seem to fail (TextRange as well) so I'm calling for some help ! :)  BTW It's in VS2010 .Net 4

Jim

```
    private void ScratchPad_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var start = ScratchPad.CaretPosition;
        var end = start.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);
        // ScratchPad is the RichTextBox !
        ScratchPad.Selection.Select(end, start);          

        var bg = ScratchPad.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty);
        var fg = ScratchPad.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty);
        var fs = ScratchPad.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty);
        var ff = ScratchPad.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty);

        //RtbFontSizes.SelectedValue = Convert.ToDouble(fs);
        //RtbFontList.SelectedValue = ff.ToString();

        ScratchPad.Selection.Select(start, start);
    }
```

Comment: maybe the background of the selection is not set/specified, that's why it's null (as expected)?
have you try set (change) the background value?

Comment: Hi, The RichTextBox is currently hosting some RTF text I built in Word as a test and the background on some specific words is yellow so nice and easy to identify as in #FFFFFF00

Comment: A bit strange behavior, i tried your code. Copy paste text with background from Word and the bg variable is null. But if the background set from code, sth like: `ScratchPad.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));`, bg will get the correct color (#FFFF0000)